# Add stenciljs component fron NPM to Vue.js application

Tags: typescript, vue.js, stenciljs, stencil-component

I don't get my tag to work in my Vue project. 
I have create a Stencil.js component test, its just the origional code from stencil when you create an web component. 
I have upload it to NPM as a public package.

So now it should just be to install and import the package in my vue app, but I cant make it work. (Vue app just build with Vue CLI and have typescript)

When I do the `npm install stencil-component-test --save` I can see the code in my node_modules, so that works.

I try to import and use it in my Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
    <my-component></my-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
import MyComponent from "stencil-component-test";

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    MyComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

Its just an empty tag if I look in chrome dev-tools. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to see the contents of the stencil-component-test package?

Comment: Yes, you can look at it and try it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/stencil-component-test

Comment: have you put <script src='https://unpkg.com/my-component@0.0.1/dist/mycomponent.js'></script> in the head of your index.html file?

Comment: @MJ_Wales I can see now that I get an 404 when I include the script-tag. It can't find the package. I don't know why tho...

Comment: Does mycomponent.js file exist in the dist folder in the my-component folder in node_modules?

Comment: I got it to work, I had the wrong name. It should be <script src='unpkg.com/my-component@0.0.1/dist/my-component.js'></…>

So now I can see it. Thanks for the help, you got me to look in to the path and guid me in the right direction! THANKS @MJ_Wales

Comment: Great! No worries.